# Is there any software or web service for club-level Elo ratings?

Tags: rating, elo

Is there any software (or web-based service) that allows you to keep track of local, club-level Elo ratings?

These ratings would not have any connection with official Elo ratings, it would be just an Elo rating within the universe of players in a club (i.e. games in various social tournaments would compute for the rating).

Comment: That's an interesting idea for a project.

Comment: I did it by hand for our local club.  Almost as easy as entering data into a program to do the work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even if it is not available, something like this is not too hard to implement yourself. Here is an example with extremely silly and simple rating system that is just meant to give you an idea. But I don't think that using actual Elo formula that much harder.

**EDIT:** I edit my implementation to use Elo formula (not including floors) given by the formula [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system)

```
def get_exp_score_a(rating_a, rating_b):
    return 1.0 /(1 + 10**((rating_b - rating_a)/400.0))

def rating_adj(rating, exp_score, score, k=32):
    return rating + k * (score - exp_score)

class ChessPlayer(object):
    def __init__(self, name, rating):
        self.rating = rating
        self.name = name
    def match(self, other, result):

        exp_score_a = get_exp_score_a(self.rating, other.rating)

        if result == self.name:
            self.rating = rating_adj(self.rating, exp_score_a, 1)
            other.rating = rating_adj(other.rating, 1 - exp_score_a, 0)
        elif result == other.name:
            self.rating = rating_adj(self.rating, exp_score_a, 0)
            other.rating = rating_adj(other.rating, 1 - exp_score_a, 1)
        elif result == 'Draw':
            self.rating = rating_adj(self.rating, exp_score_a, 0.5)
            other.rating = rating_adj(other.rating, 1 - exp_score_a, 0.5)
```

This works as follows:

```
>>> bob = ChessPlayer('Bob', 1600)
>>> john = ChessPlayer('John', 1900)
>>> bob.rating
1600
>>> john.rating
1900
>>> bob.match(john, 'Bob')
>>> bob.rating
1627.1686541692377
>>> john.rating
1872.8313458307623
>>> mark = ChessPlayer('Mark', 2100)
>>> mark.match(bob, 'Draw')
>>> mark.rating
2085.974306956907
>>> bob.rating
1641.1943472123305
```

Here is my original python implementation:

```
class ChessPlayer(object):
    def __init__(self, name, rating):
        self.rating = rating
        self.name = name
    def match(self, other, result):
        if result == self.name:
            self.rating += 10
            other.rating -= 10
        elif result == other.name:
            self.rating += 10
            other.rating -= 10
        elif result == 'Draw':
            pass
```

This works as follows:

```
>>> bob = ChessPlayer('Bob', 1600)
>>> john = ChessPlayer('John', 1900)
>>> bob.match(john, 'Bob')
>>> bob.rating
1610
>>> john.rating
1890
>>> mark = ChessPlayer('Mark', 2100)
>>> mark.match(bob, 'Mark')
>>> mark.rating
2110
>>> bob.rating
1600
>>> mark.match(john, 'Draw')
>>> mark.rating
2110
>>> john.rating
1890
```

Comment: I think Elo is possibly just as simple as that. :)

Comment: Nice. If the OP wanted to modify this with, say, the actual USCF rating algorithm, the mathematical details are available in Section 2 of this document: http://www.glicko.net/ratings/rating.system.pdf

Comment: Thanks, but I got really curios and implemented the Elo formula myself :).

Comment: For a small universe such as chess club, I think it is best that there are no floors, otherwise you would get soon inflation if very weak players play a lot.

Comment: for local club ratings all the complexity of elo glicko whatever are just not going to add any real benefit

Answer (score 8):

It seems that [rankade](https://rankade.com), our ranking system for sports, games, and more, fits your needs.

It's free to use and it's designed to manage **rankings** (and **stats**, including matchup stats, and more) for small to large groups of players.

Rankade doesn't use **Elo**, but its algorithm (called *ree* algorithm), although more complex (here's a [comparison](https://rankade.com/ree#ranking-system-comparison) between most known rating system, including *Elo*, *Glicko* and *TrueSkill*), is similar to Elo if you play 1-on-1 matches only.

Comment: very cool webapp!

Comment: I have tried it and it seems suits my needs; Simple, clean, can add players after a match has started. I would like to suggest that allow user to custom CSS. Just made available a textarea (or contenteditable div) for user to paste their CSS

Answer (score 4):

I just downloaded and played around with a lightweight freeware item for Windows called [ELORater](http://www.garnergaggle.org/papa/chess/ELORater/) that seems to provide what you're after. You can create a "group" for your club, and then add players to the group, along with whatever initial ratings you want them to have. Then you can just input the results of any games that get played and the program maintains an updated list of player ratings for you.

Comment: is it still online?

Comment: @Aubrey: A simple web search for "ELORater" sent me to this GitHub page: https://github.com/steelfire81/EloRater

Answer (score 3):

The free Excel add-in Chess Ranking Assistant found at https://www.add-ins.com/free-products/chess-ranking-assistant.htm uses the glicko system and is menu driven for easy of use. It is designed for chess clubs

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still looking for something like this, I've build a fairly simple one here:
https://github.com/richardadalton/EloRate

At the moment you'll have to host it yourself, but I may offer a hosted service in the future.

-Rd

Answer (score 1):

I recently built https://sortmatch.ca to do this kind of thing. It uses Glicko2 instead of Elo, but the effect is roughly equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

https://skillrank.games

Also allows ratings for team games where individuals change teams between games

Answer (score 0):

http://elorankings.com

Allows you to create custom elo rankings and control certain parameters. Mostly used by video game communities but can be done to create rankings and manage elo ratings for anything. Very easy to use. Keeps complete match history and allows you to individually see a players history, W-L, and how their score changed per match. I use it for a smash tournament I run every week: http://elorankings.com/rankings.aspx?id=1

Comment: Site seems to be down or not live anymore

Answer (score 0):

Yeah sure, you can take a look at http://www.chessfiles.com/chess-software.html

Answer (score 0):

The [Irish Chess Union](https://www.icu.ie/) has [its rating web application](https://ratings.icu.ie/) fully released as Open Source and it's available on GitHub: https://github.com/ninkibah/icu_ratings_app